# Extract column from dataframe and create new column using regex

Tags: python, regex

**My Dataframe**

```
Ticket       short_description
RQ01    The Job obe_fin_r3_003 failed. | xyz418.domain.NET
RQ02    The Job ouk_log_r3_002_am failed. | abc418.domain.NET
```

**My Objective**

I am trying to extract the Job name i.e obe_fin_r3_003 into a new column and xyz418 into a new column.

**My Code**

```
text = re.compile(r'The\s+job\s+(\w+)')
df['server'] = list(map(lambda x: x.group(1) or "", map(text.search, df['short_description'])))
df['job'] = list(map(lambda x: x.split(".NET")[0].split()[-1], df['short_description']))
```

**My Error**

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

**Question**

Why this error occurs? How can I solve it? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated Answers:

You can use the [Series.str.findall()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) option to get all the values.

Your request:

1. Extract the job name from the short description
2. Extract the prefix details of the job name that contains `log` or `fin` in the short description
   Note: If not found, it will store NaN
3. Extract the suffix details of the job name that contains `log` or `fin` in the short description
   Note: If not found, it will store NaN
4. Extract the server name from the short description
5. Extract the server name only if the name ends with .NET in the short description.
   Note: If not found, it will store NaN

The full code is shown below. The previous answer has explanation for each section.

To help you, I have added a third row that does not meet the criteria. You will see that it pulls the correct information as per the above requirements.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',None)
Ticket     = ['RQ01','RQ02','RQ03']
short_desc = ['The Job obe_fin_r3_003 failed. | xyz418.domain.NET',
              'The Job ouk_log_r3_002_am failed. | abc418.domain.NET',
              'The Job our_dim_r4_004_pm failed. | dim418.domain.COM']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticket':Ticket,'short_description':short_desc})
df['job'] = df.short_description.str.findall(r'(\w+\_\w+)').str[0]
df['job_before'] = df.short_description.str.findall('\w+_fin_|\w+_log_').str[0].str.split('_').str[0]
df['job_after'] = df.short_description.str.findall('_fin_\w+|_log_\w+').str[0].str.split('_',2).str[2]
df['job_fin_log'] = df.short_description.str.contains('_fin_|_log_')

df['server'] = df.short_description.str.findall(r'(\| \w+)').str[0].str[2:]
df['server_name'] = df.short_description.str.findall(r'(\| \w+)(\.\w+\.)NET$').str[0].str[0].str[2:]

print (df[['Ticket','short_description']])
print (df[['job','job_before','job_after','job_fin_log','server','server_name']])
```

The output of the above code will be:

```
  Ticket                                      short_description
0   RQ01     The Job obe_fin_r3_003 failed. | xyz418.domain.NET
1   RQ02  The Job ouk_log_r3_002_am failed. | abc418.domain.NET
2   RQ03  The Job our_dim_r4_004_pm failed. | dim418.domain.COM


                 job job_before  job_after  job_fin_log  server server_name
0     obe_fin_r3_003        obe     r3_003         True  xyz418      xyz418
1  ouk_log_r3_002_am        ouk  r3_002_am         True  abc418      abc418
2  our_dim_r4_004_pm        NaN        NaN        False  dim418         NaN
```

## Previous Answers:

You can use the [Series.str.findall()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) option to get the value. It is similar to re.findall(). I have shared the link to the documentation. Please read through them to learn more.

The assumption for job:

1. There is only one job name in the row
2. The pattern is `chars_chars` with a space before and after the pattern ends

The assumption for server name is:

1. There is only one server name in the row
2. The pattern is `chars.chars` with a space before and after the pattern ends

Then the code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
Ticket     = ['RQ01','RQ02']
short_desc = ['The Job obe_fin_r3_003 failed. | xyz418.domain.NET','The Job ouk_log_r3_002_am failed. | abc418.domain.NET']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticket':Ticket,'short_description':short_desc})
df['job'] = df.short_description.str.findall(r'(\w+\_\w+)').str[0]
df['server'] = df.short_description.str.findall(r'(\w+\.\w+)').str[0]
print (df)
```

The output will be:

```
>>> df[['job','server']]
                 job         server
0     obe_fin_r3_003  xyz418.domain
1  ouk_log_r3_002_am  abc418.domain
```

If you need just the first part of servername without .domain, then you can give

```
df['server'] = df.short_description.str.findall(r'(\| \w+)').str[0].str[2:]
```

This will give you:

```
                 job  server
0     obe_fin_r3_003  xyz418
1  ouk_log_r3_002_am  abc418
```

And if you are very specific that it has to be a server that endswith .NET, then you can also do this. The regEx part is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ffx3Qf/1/):

```
df['server1'] = df.short_description.str.findall(r'(\| \w+)(\.\w+\.)NET$').str[0].str[0].str[2:]
```

In this case, you are forcing it to find a patter starting with `| chars.` and `.chars.` and ends with `NET`. Then you want to pick the first string, and then the 3rd char onwards.

Same result.

```
                 job  server
0     obe_fin_r3_003  xyz418
1  ouk_log_r3_002_am  abc418
```

I am not sure what part of the job details you want. Here's the code to get you the left hand side and right hand side of `fin` or `log` info.

```
df['job'] = df.short_description.str.findall(r'(\w+\_\w+)').str[0]
df['job_before'] = df.short_description.str.findall('\w+_fin_|\w+_log_').str[0].str.split('_').str[0]
df['job_after'] = df.short_description.str.findall('_fin_\w+|_log_\w+').str[0].str.split('_',2).str[2]
print (df[['job','job_before','job_after']])
```

The output will be:

```
                 job job_before  job_after
0     obe_fin_r3_003        obe     r3_003
1  ouk_log_r3_002_am        ouk  r3_002_am
```

And if you want to find out if the row has `fin` or `log`, then you can use:

```
df['job_fin_log'] = df.short_description.str.contains('_fin_|_log_')
```

You will get the result as:

```
                 job job_before  job_after  job_fin_log
0     obe_fin_r3_003        obe     r3_003         True
1  ouk_log_r3_002_am        ouk  r3_002_am         True
```

Comment: thank you, It is working. But I need server name like xyz418,abc418

Comment: If we want to extract the "fin" and "log" part from the Job part now? What will be the regex part?

Comment: can i get more info on the ask. What do you mean fin and log part. Do you want everything after `fin` and `log`? or before?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without regex, Try this -

> Individual Functions -

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> val1 = ['RQ01','RQ02']
>>> val2 = ['The Job obe_fin_r3_003 failed. | xyz418.domain.NET','The Job ouk_log_r3_002_am failed. | abc418.domain.NET']

>>> d = {'Ticket':val1,'short_desription':val2}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
  Ticket                                   short_desription
0   RQ01  The Job obe_fin_r3_003 failed. | xyz418.domain...
1   RQ02  The Job ouk_log_r3_002_am failed. | abc418.dom...


def extract_server(inp):
    temp = list(map(str.strip,inp.split('|')))
    res = temp[1].split('.')[0]
    return res

def extract_jn(inp):
    temp = list(map(str.strip,inp.split('|')))
    res = temp[0].split()[2]
    return res.strip()

>>> df['short_desription'].apply(lambda extract_server(x))
0    xyz418
1    abc418
Name: short_desription, dtype: object

>>> df['short_desription'].apply(lambda x:extract_jn(x))
0       obe_fin_r3_003
1    ouk_log_r3_002_am
Name: short_desription, dtype: object
```

> Combined Function -

```
def extract_meta(inp):
    temp = list(map(str.strip,inp.split('|')))
    jb = temp[0].split()[2].strip()
    sn = temp[1].split('.')[0].strip()
    return jb,sn


>>> df['jobname'],df['servername'] = zip(*df['short_desription'].apply(extract_meta))
>>> df
  Ticket                                   short_desription            jobname servername
0   RQ01  The Job obe_fin_r3_003 failed. | xyz418.domain...     obe_fin_r3_003     xyz418
1   RQ02  The Job ouk_log_r3_002_am failed. | abc418.dom...  ouk_log_r3_002_am     abc418
```

Comment: I need to extract the Job name as well.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update, but now I am getting IndexError: list index out of range, when using my data frame. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also I see that the combined code is separting the jobname and servername in the same row

Comment: @SUSHANTPARIHAR - Yes , it is a row wise operation , and can you paste your error that you are experiencing

Comment: You dont need to do apply. Why not use Series.str.findall to get what you want?